# npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-myreactnativeapp - Not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I installed the Expo CLI and Node version 12

When I tried to create a new react native project I get this error

[See error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsCHv.png)

Error

PS C:\Users\leosu\Documents\GitProjects> npm init myreactnativeapp
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-myreactnativeapp - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'create-myreactnativeapp@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\leosu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-12T23_54_32_833Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-myreactnativeapp@latest' ] failed with code 1
PS C:\Users\leosu\Documents\GitProjects>

**Any ideas on how to solve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Expo it should be:

```
expo init myreactnativeapp
```

Instead of `npm init myreactnativeapp`

Assuming that you already ran `npm install -g expo-cli`

Comment: That was it! Thank you!